# Restoring the default KDE Desktop?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, lubuntu, kde, restore

Sorry, I am still a newbie on Linux, I was installing earlier some new DEs, I made fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.04, installed, then added KUBUNUTU-DESKTOP, LUBUNTU-DESKTOP and GNOME...

then when I wanted to test my new KDE things were kinda, *weird* instead of the normal KDE 4.10.5 desktop *I mean the place with the wallpaper, short-cuts and widgets are*,
I got this weird looking thing, that is like a blue outdated ugly version of the old gnome 3 dash....

I want back my default desktop....

any ideas? Dx

Screenshots attached below:

WHAT I GOT:
[image]

WHAT I WANT (BACK):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like a few gnome desktop elements made its way through kde.

first off, you should follow the link for the "possible duplicate of..." above, as the old config might fix kde

otherwise, if you don't need gnome anymore, you could try removing it from dah package manager or with sudo apt-get remove gnome..

you also may want to check your auto-starting apps and make sure they are the kde varients, sometimes when you use gnome and lxde based apps, they start to leak their desktop elements with it :O

Comment: None of those worked Dx
the topic isnt a duplicate, i just want to remove that blue dash thing, i dont want to restore the actual desktop...*same name to 2 things can be a annoying thing sometimes...
i have checked for autostart apps, tried restoring the desktop in 3 different ways and nothing worked....i already did this installation once, but i installed gnome 1st then KDE, i guess i will have to unninstall both and do it in the correct order....Dxx

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but KDE's configuration is stored in a hidden folder at your home called `~/.kde`. Under normal conditions (I mean, with one DE) you can delete this folder so it gets recreated with default settings next time you log in.

It occurs to me that maybe you could try either deleting that folder to restore default configuration or try to find if GNOME as a similar folder which can be deleted so it does not interfere with KDE.

If you have one partition for `/` and a different one for `/home` , another option could be to install a default Kubuntu and format `/` partition but keep the `/home` one so you would not lose any custom configuration or data (images, videos, documents, files...) and you would only have to install any custom software or driver.